# Question about common values across columns

Tags: r, excel, statistics, stat

I have a set of 20 column, each contains number value. I would like to have a function in excel or in r or somewhere else to extract the shared values among all the columns.

Several of the online Venn tools can visualize and list among up to 6 columns.

Any tool?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the data and an example of what you want to do to it?

Answer (score 1):

in `R`, we can use `intersect` with `Reduce` to get the common values across all the columns

```
Reduce(intersect, dftest)
```

#### data

```
dftest <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 2:6, col3 = 3:7)
```